# How to call get fragmentManger in a fragment ANDROID

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-datepicker

I am trying to use a date and time picker in a fragment, and I am some what basing my code off of [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html). I access the my fragmentManager in my activity from my fragment so I can use a datepicker in my fragment like below:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.dateButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            datePickerDialog.setVibrate(isVibrate());
            datePickerDialog.setYearRange(2015, 2020);
            datePickerDialog.setCloseOnSingleTapDay(isCloseOnSingleTapDay());
            datePickerDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),DATEPICKER_TAG);
        }
    });
```

The error that I get here is on the last line 'Cannot resolve method "show(android.app.FragmentManger, String). But unless the method has deprecated (Havent read anything about that) then I think I am just not supplying a proper fragment manager. Any advice to get the error to go away and make the date picker show up?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If your activity extends ActionBarActivity, then you should try `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `DialogFragment` you're using extends from the `Fragment` in the support library. So change your code to (supposing you are inside a support fragment):

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        datePickerDialog.setVibrate(isVibrate());
        datePickerDialog.setYearRange(2015, 2020);
        datePickerDialog.setCloseOnSingleTapDay(isCloseOnSingleTapDay());
        datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),DATEPICKER_TAG);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks vinitus this worked for me. But now my main activity doesn't want to replace my current layout with this fragment because its no longer extends fragment, but instead DialogFragment. Shouldn't it know that Dialog Fragment is an extension of Fragment?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. What's going on?

Comment: I call this line in my mainActivity:        ft.replace(R.id.mainContainer, sessFrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
But it is giving me an error saying FragmentTranscation cannot be applied to SessionSetUpFragment, it must be a Fragment. SessionSetUpFragment is the fragment that extends DialogFragment